# how to set modal bottom sheet sized based on its content while expanded child is used in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a container and expanded listview inside showmodelbottomsheet ..

by default modalbottomsheet occupy 50% height of screen height..Thats fine when data are bigger... but i want to size bottom sheet to minimum height when data are less...

listview should be in scrolling way..

```
Scaffold(
      body: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Center(child: Text('Data')),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(data[index]),
                            );
                          }),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              });
        },
        child: Text('Show Bottom Sheet'),
      ),
    ))
```

here is an image , i wantt to remove this blank space in expanded widget

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Replace the `Expanded` widget with `Flexible`.
- Add `shrinkWrap: true` to the `ListView` widget.

Final result:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Center(child: Text('Data')),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(data[index]),
                            );
                          }),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              });
        },
        child: Text('Show Bottom Sheet'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
                isScrollControlled: true,
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 50,
                        child: const Center(child: Text('Data')),
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: 5,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return const ListTile(
                              title: Text("Sample"),
                            );
                          })
                    ],
                  );
                });
          },
          child: Text('Show Bottom Sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
```